# Proxy tomcat urls to map a host request to a path

Tags: redirect, tomcat6, host, subdirectory

how, if possible, can I redirect a request for a hostname to a specific subdirectory of one of the deployed apps?

E.g., I wish to forward

```
http://host.com
```

to

```
http://host.com/app/path
```

It is however possible to redirect to a specific application on tomcat, e.g.,

```
    <Host name="host.com" appBase="webapps">
        <Context path="/" docBase="webapps/app" debug="6"/>
    </Host>
```

But I've never managed to redirect it to a subpath of an application. I'd fancy a tomcat-only approach over using an external mod_proxy with apache2 to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not seem possible. Final solution was to use mod_proxy of Apache2 to proxy the request.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me by changing path to `""` (i.e. making it default web app for the Host)

```
<Host name="host.com" appBase="webapps">
            <Context path="" docBase="webapps/app" debug="6"/>
        </Host>
```

It serves static files correctly, but my JSTL fails now.

Anyways, can you try?

Comment: hmm, to me, both approaches seem to have the same impact. That is, it allows me to associate "host.com" with "host.com/app", but not with "host.com/app/path".